# How to have geom_point and geom_bar side by side and with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine a scatterplot with a bar plot. The bar plot should be on the right side of the scatterplot of each corresponding group specified in facet wrap. The two plots have the same unit on the y axis but the scaling of the bar might need to be adjusted so the barplot it's not too tall.

Here's an example.

```
data(mpg)
```

So far I have tried this, but I would the bar should be outside the scatterplot area. Additionally, in my data the x axis in the barplot is a factor with two levels, so it has a discrete scale and my scatterplot has a continuous x scale.

```
ggplot()+geom_bar(data=mpg,aes(x=10,y=displ,fill=trans),stat='identity',position='stack')
+geom_point(data=mpg,aes(x=displ,y=displ))+facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

Can I achieve to plot these two plot types side-by-side or do I have to use something like cowplot? I think that if I have to combine plots outside ggplot I will not be able to use factor_wrap, so I guess I have to do a for loop for each factor level and then combine everything?